# Can WebRTC scale based on CPU/GPU performance

Tags: webrtc

I know that WebRTC can scale based on the network connection. But what I'd like to know if it also takes into account the performance of the PC. Let's assume we're using Google Chrome.

So for example:

- I start a videochat with 2 other people.
- I have a 720p webcam, my maxWidth and maxHeight are 1280x720.
- All three participants have a perfect internet connection (theoretically)
- I and one other participant have a perfect computer (theoretically)
- The other participant has a computer which CPU/GPU can not handle my full quality/resolution stream, it does not have enough processing power.

Would WebRTC scale down the quality/resolution of the participant with the inadequate PC?

Comment: It's more than just CPU power, as the system can be loaded with other tasks. But obviously webRTC doesn't provide Scalable Video Coding out of the box at the moment http://www.nojitter.com/post/240168352/implementing-svc-in-webrtc

Comment: Of course, but the amount of data transmitted can be scaled to allow for a fluent image on a poor connection. Would that not also bring down the required processing power needed to process the image and audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, WebRTC can account for CPU overuse detection (I'm not sure about GPU, specifically). Here's the [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1577) where this was added to the WebRTC project. It's not consistent across implementations, either.

If you run [this sample](http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/) in Chrome you can see a statistic reported by `getStats` called `googCpuLimitedResolution: false` which would be `true` if the resolution was limited by overuse detection in the CPU.

Comment: Thanks! Thats about the best answer I'll get I guess. Any way too see where it has been implemented? I'm guessing the stable version for all major platforms?